# I want to bring all the columns from laravel at once

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

The "users" table contains the name, age, and addr columns. If I want to print these three columns, I need to do something like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name.",";
    echo $user->age.",";
    echo $user->addr."<br>";
}
```

I want to output all the columns, even if not each. So I tried this.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    print_r($user);
}
```

result.

```
App\Model\Users Object
(
    [timestamps] => 
    [connection:protected] => mysql
    [table:protected] => main_settings
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
......
```

I did not get the result I wanted. How can I display all the columns at once?

Comment: Try dump instead of print r but long answer short of you are wanting to render it in the blade you can't you need to reference the object

Comment: use dd() instead of print_r()

Answer (score 0):

After registering the question, I found the answer.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get()->toArray();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    print_r($user);
}
```

Using toArray () gives me the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make use of model in laravel to add/edit/delete/fetch data.
you can try the below code for fetching the user table data.

```
$users = App\User::all();
foreach($users as $user) {
    dd($user);
}
```

Note : use User model in your class before accessing it.

If you want to fetch data using SQL Raw query then try the below code.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

foreach ($users as $key=>$user) {
    dd($key,$user);
}
```